# change msdn language links

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, languages

Something minor but i thought it would be convenient. I got a link to `http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/...`. I didnt remember the english path right away but within 5 seconds i found it and changed the url (total maybe 6 seconds).

As you can guess, not a big deal but i thought it would be convenient to change the language to either english or whatever language the user sets to his/her profile.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good note but (in my opinion) a bad suggestion. The difficulty comes from the fact that the MSDN documentation is not consistent across languages. For the most part it generally is, but not always.

Also, comments are 100% *not* consistent across languages. So, assuming that the pages exist in other languages, it is not guaranteed that the content will ever be 100% the same. Any algorithmic or automatic changes to links would need to be (IMO) close to 100% valid, and changing languages isn't really anywhere near that.

But it *is* a very valid concern. As the language of the site is English, anyone posting links in another language is theoretically posting something which might be completely unhelpful to the user, because they cannot understand it.

Therefore, the **most** I would be willing to support is a pop-up that says

> "Your link is culture specific {http://somedomain.com/**fr-FR**/somepage.aspx}. Proceed or Cancel?"

or something to that effect when you tried to post a link. This shouldn't be that hard to detect, but it could quite possibly be quite annoying, so even that much might be too far.

Comment: Good point. +1. Maybe this could be applied when the user clicks on a link recognized to be in a different language. A prompt could be done for the user instead with a msg saying it can be disabled in the user settings. Or the user can just outright say convert the links for me and perhaps use a little jquery to show a symbol next to the link. but all i care about is the idea of the suggestion. I was quiet confused for a second and in my case he is linking to a .NET function and made no reference to check the comments.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me all the time with `de.php.net/` links. On the other hand, auto-correction can be dangerous and annoying for so many reasons. Maybe it should be asking "convert?" upon pasting.... Which, judging from past efforts on internationalization, will make this go way down to the bottom of the priorities list :D

It's not really a big deal, but still, a good point. +1.